# C language - counting number of different vowels with no pointers or additional functions

Tags: c

I got this exercise that I haven't been able to solve, the point is to create a program where you type in a text, then the program analyzes each word of the text and counts the vowels of each word, then the program returns in screen the number of words that have 3 or more different vowels, and by different I mean, it doesn't matter if the word has 3 "a", it only count as one (the word has the vowels "a", it doesn't matter how many times), so for example, the word "above" has 3 vowels, the word "been" has 1 vowels, the word "example" has 2 vowels. The vowels can be upper case or lower case, it doesn't matter, and here is the tricky part: It cannot contain any pointers or functions made by us.

what i did was asking the user to enter word by word so the program analyze each word, and then at the end returns the number of words that contain 3 or more vowels, but I feel like there must be an easier way where the user can type a complete paragraph or text, then the program analyzes each word and return the number of words that have 3 or more different vowels.

Anyway, my code is as follows, any suggestions would be appreciated:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

main() {

    int vowels, text, words, c, total=0,a=0,e=0,i=0,o=0,u=0;


    printf ("How many words does your text has? ");
    scanf("%d",&words);

    for(c=1;c<=words;c++){

        printf("Type your word %d, after that press enter, then press 'control' and 'z' at the same time, and then press enter again: \n", c);

        while (EOF != (text=getchar())){

            if (text == 'a' || text == 'A'){    
                a++;
                if (a >=2){
                    a = 1;
                }
            }

            if (text == 'e' || text == 'E'){
                e++;
                if (e >=2){
                    e = 1;
                }
            }

            if (text == 'i' || text == 'I'){
                i++;
                if (i >=2){
                    i = 1;
                }
            }

            if (text == 'o' || text == 'O'){
                o++;
                if (o >=2){
                    o = 1;
                }
            }

            if (text == 'u' || text == 'U'){
                u++;
                if (u >=2){
                    u = 1;
                }
            }
        }

        vowels = a+e+i+o+u;

        if(vowels >=3){
            total = total +1;  
        }

        a=0,e=0,i=0,o=0,u=0;
        vowels = 0;   
    }

    printf("\n\nThe total of words with 3 or more vowels is: %d", total);
    printf("\n");

    total=0;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: “Vowel” not “vocal”.

Comment: Probably https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is better place for this question.

Answer (score 2):

In order to read and analyze a single word, or a paragraph words to determine the number of words that contain at least three different vowels (of any case), this is one of the rare times when reading input with `scanf` (using the `'%s'` *format specifier*) actually is a reasonable choice.

Recall the `'%s'` *format specifier* will read characters up to the first whitespace. That gives you a simple way to read a word at a time from `stdin`. To end input, the user simply need to generate an `EOF` by entering `ctrl+d` (or `ctrl+z` on windows). This satisfies your paragraph requirement.

For parsing, you can take advantage of converting each character to lower case to simplify checking for vowels. Using a frequency array of `5` elements provides a simple way to track the number of different vowels found in each word. Then a final test to see if the number of vowels found equals the required number is all you need before incrementing your total word count for words with three different vowels.

A simple implementation would be something similar to:

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum { NREQD = 3, NVOWEL = 5, MAXC = 128 };    /* declare constants */

int main (void) {

    char word[MAXC] = "";   /* word buffer */
    size_t wordcnt = 0;     /* words with 3 different vowels */

    printf ("enter a word(s) below, [ctrl+d on blank line to end]\n");
    for (;;) {
        int vowels[NVOWEL] = {0},   /* frequency array */
            vowelcnt = 0,           /* vowels per-word */
            rtn;                    /* scanf return */
        if ((rtn = scanf ("%127s", word)) == EOF)   /* chk EOF */
            break;
        for (int i = 0; word[i]; i++) { /* loop over each char */
            if ('A' <= word[i] && word[i] <= 'Z')   /* check upper */
                word[i] ^= 'a' - 'A';   /* convert to lower */
            switch (word[i]) {          /* check if vowel */
                case 'a':   vowels[0] = 1; break;
                case 'e':   vowels[1] = 1; break;
                case 'i':   vowels[2] = 1; break;
                case 'o':   vowels[3] = 1; break;
                case 'u':   vowels[4] = 1; break;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < NVOWEL; i++)    /* loop over array */
            if (vowels[i])                  /* check index */
                vowelcnt++;                 /* increment vowelcnt */
        if (vowelcnt >= NREQD)  /* do we have at least 3 vowels? */
            wordcnt++;          /* increment wordcnt */
    }

    printf ("\nThere are %zu words with %d different vowels.\n",
            wordcnt, NREQD);
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/vowelcnt
enter a word(s) below, [ctrl+d on blank line to end]
Everyone Understands That The Dictionary Doesn't Track
Words That Contain Vowels Like It Does Etimology.

There are 4 words with 3 different vowels.
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: A much more elegant solution than mine :)

Comment: Your is good as well. There is always more than one way to skin a cat in C.

Comment: It's tempting just to write `vowelcnt = vowels[0] + vowels[1] + vowels[2] + vowels[3] + vowels[4]`.  If you do loop, the `if` is really not necessary; it takes at least as long as simply adding the number which will do no damage if the value is 0 (and the only alternative is 1 since you carefully set the value to 1 rather than incrementing it in the switch).

Comment: Note that an etymologist does indeed have three vowels in the word, but an etymologist would complain about misspelling 'etymology' with an 'i' in place of the first 'y'.

Comment: (certain linguistic liberties were taken for purpose of the example `:)` And point well taken on the summation loop. Simple addition would have been optimal.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `fgets` to read a whole line. I don't know how you define a
paragraph though, do you mean just a long text or a collection of lines? You can
copy & paste multiple lines in the console and if you loop using `fgets`, then
you get all the lines. But allowing the user to enter multiple lines at once,
it's more tricky, because you should know how many lines the user will input.
That's why I'd say focus on reading the text line by line.

Your solution reads characters by characters and you are ignoring non-vowels.
That's OK, but you are not detecting words like you should do. The `for` loop
makes no sense, because in the first iteration you enter in a `while` loop that
is only going to leave when there are no more characters to read from `stdin`.
So the next iteration of the `for` loop will not enter the `while` loop and you
won't be reading anything any more.

You are also repeating too much code, I know you assignment says not to use your
own functions, but this can be improved with a simple look up table by creating
an array of chars using the characters as an index for the array. I'll explain
that in the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(void)
{
    char line[1024];

    // initializing look ups with 0
    int lookup_vowels[1 << CHAR_BIT] = { 0 };

    // using 'a', 'e' as index for the lookup table
    // if you want to know if a character is a vowel,
    // lookup_vowels[character] will be 1 if character is
    // a vowel, 0 otherwise
    lookup_vowels['a'] = lookup_vowels['e'] = lookup_vowels['i'] = 
            lookup_vowels['o'] = lookup_vowels['u'] = 1;

    // for parsing word with strtok
    const char *delim = " \t\r\n";

    int num_of_words = 0;

    printf("Enter some text, to end input press ENTER and then CTRL+D\n");

    while(1)
    {
        if(fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin) == NULL)
            break;

        // parsing words
        char *word = strtok(line, delim);
        if(word == NULL)
            continue; // the line has only delimiters, ignore it

        do {
            // will be access with the same principle as the lookup
            // table, the character is the index
            int present[1 << CHAR_BIT] = { 0 };

            size_t len = strlen(word);

            for(size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i)
            {
                // I'll explain later the meaning
                int c = tolower(word[i]);
                if(lookup_vowels[c])
                    present[c] = 1; // set the present for a vowel to 1
            }


            int count = present['a'] + present['e'] + present['i'] + present['o']
                + present['u'];

            if(count > 2)
            {
                printf("'%s' has more than three distinct vowels\n", word);
                num_of_words++;
            }

        } while((word = strtok(NULL, delim)));
    }

    printf("The number of word with three or more distinct vowels: %d\n", num_of_words);

    return 0;
}
```

So let me quickly explain some of the technique I use here:

The lookup table is an array of size 256 because a `char` is 8-bit<sup>1</sup>
value and can have 256 different values (range [0,255]). The idea is that this
array is initialized with 0 overall (`int lookup_vowels[1<<CHAR_BIT] = { 0 };`) and then
I set to 1 only in 5 places: at the position of the vowels using their
[ASCII](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ascii.7.html) value as index.

So instead of doing the repeating task if checking

```
// where c is a char
if(c == 'a' || c == 'A')
    a=1;
}
```

for all vowels, I just can do

```
int idx = tolower(c);
if(lookup_vowels[idx])
{
    // c is a vowel
}
```

The `present` variable function similar to the lookup table, here I use the
ASCII code of a vowel as index and set it to 1 if a vowel is present in `word`.
After scanning all characters in `word`, I sum all values stored in `present`.
If the value is greater than 2, then the word has at least 3 or more distinct
vowels and the counter variable is increased.

The function [`strtok`](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/3-strtok/) is used to split the line using a defined set of
delimiters, in this case the empty character, tab, carriage return and line
feed. To start parsing the line, `strtok` must be called with the source string
as the first argument and the delimiters as the second argument. All other
subsequent calls must pass `NULL` as the first argument. The function returns a
pointer to the next word and returns `NULL` when no more words have been found.

When a word is found, it calculates the number of distinct vowels and checks if
this number is greater than 2.

---

**fotenotes**

<sup>1</sup>`CHAR_BIT` defined in `limits.h` returns the number of bits of byte.
Usually a byte is 8-bit wide, so I could have written 256 instead. But there are
"exotic" architectures where a byte is not 8-bit long, so by doing `1<<CHAR_BIT`
I'm getting the correct dimension.